make4ht: Configure the hyperlink to open in a new tab
I am using make4ht for the conversion from tex to html file with the following configuration.
What I need to configure is related to URLs and hyperlinks. I want to get the hyperlink settings of the html file such that single-clicking on each hyperlink would open the URL on a new tab on the browser.
cv.tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}%
    \begin{shaded}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}%
    \end{shaded}%
  }\vspace{-11pt}%
}
\newcommand{\school}[4]{\vspace{1.5mm}
  \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} \vspace{1.5mm}
}

\newenvironment{education}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}{\end{itemize}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{\Large Name} & \textbf{June, 2021} \\ Address & \textit{\href{mailto:}{Email}}
\end{tabular*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{education} 
       \item[]
            \school
            {University Name}
            {City, Country}
            {BSc - Physics}
            {2010 - 2014}
\end{education}
          
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Technical Skills}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
          \begin{itemize}
            \item C++, Python
            \item \href{https://www.latex-project.org/}{\LaTeX}
          \end{itemize}
\end{document}

mycfg.cfg
\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}

% handle bullet in education
\ConfigureEnv{education}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="education">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding as you like
\Css{.education ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:0em;}}
\Css{.education ul.itemize1 li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}}
\Css{.education ul.itemize2 li{list-style:disc outside;display:list-item; }}

% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}

\catcode`\:=11
% convert shadecolor to CSS
\get:xcolorcss{shadecolor}{\:shadecolor}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 3px solid \:shadecolor;box-sizing:border-box;padding:1px;background:black;}}
\catcode`\:=12

% handle \school
\renewcommand{\school}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \textbf{#1} & #2\\ \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}

% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 70ch}}

% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble


You can configure hyperlinks using \Configure{Link}:
\Configure{Link}..............4

   Configures \Link...\EndLink so that

     #1 replaces `a'
     #2 replaces `href='
     #3 replaces `name='
     #4 replaces `#'.  If empty, the older value remains in effect.

  Examples:

   \Configure{Link}{a}{href=}{name=}{}
   \Configure{Link}{ref}{target=}{id=}{\empty}

To open a link in a new tab, use the target="_blank" attribute of the <a> element. So this configuration should work:
 \Configure{Link}{a}{target="_blank" href=}{id=}{}

It creates markup like this, which seems to work:
<a href='https://www.latex-project.org/' target='_blank'><span class='LATEX'>L<span class='A'>A</span><span class='TEX'>T<span class='E'>E</span>X</span></span></a>

This is the full config file, with the above configuration:
\Preamble{xhtml,fancylogo}

% handle bullet in education
\ConfigureEnv{education}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="education">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
% set padding as you like
\Css{.education ul.itemize1{list-style:none;display:block;padding-left:0em;}}
\Css{.education ul.itemize1 li{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}}
\Css{.education ul.itemize2 li{list-style:disc outside;display:list-item; }}

% heading boxes
\renewcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="resheading">}%
\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{#1}%
\HCode{</div>}%
}
\Configure{Link}{a}{target="_blank" href=}{id=}{}

\catcode`\:=11
% convert shadecolor to CSS
\get:xcolorcss{shadecolor}{\:shadecolor}
\Css{.resheading .colorbox{display:block; width:100\%;padding:3pt;font-size: 1.2em; font-weight:bold; box-sizing:border-box;}}
\Css{.resheading{border: 3px solid \:shadecolor;box-sizing:border-box;padding:1px;background:black;}}
\catcode`\:=12

% handle \school
\renewcommand{\school}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{l r}%
  \textbf{#1} & #2\\ \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\%
\end{tabular}%
}

% document styling
\Css{body{margin: 1em auto; max-width: 70ch}}

% table styling
\Css{table{width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble



Thank you. But a MWE would be really helpful to understand.

@raf I've  added the full config file. Does it help?

I get it now. Previously, I misunderstood that you suggested replacing \href with a custom command in tex file.  Thank you.

By the way, was there any specific reason to put the line \Configure{Link}{a}{target="_blank" href=}{id=}{} to that specific position in the config?

@raf yes, the part that adds id= is not used in most cases, so you need to use target with the href part. This way they are always used together.

No, I meant to ask, you have placed the line between the \reshaeding command and its CSS setup. Was there any reason behind it?

@raf oh, no, that was completely random. It can be placed anywhere between \Preamble and \EndPreamble, and it shouldn't have a difference in this case.

Thanks again for the clarification.

Can you please check and help with this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721910/114006

@raf sure, I was offline for few days, I was able to take a look at this just now.
